# How to select an 'or' value?

Tags: excel

I have a column in my Excel file where they used to enter the email IDs. But unfortunately some guys entered multiple emails separated by an "OR" 
Something like this: `example1@email.com or myemail@domain.com`

Is there any formula to get the first email from this cell for all rows and place it in another cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first will get the first email, you can change the formula to the one below to find the second
       `=IF(ISERROR(FIND(" OR ",Email address cell))=TRUE, Email address cell,LEFT(Email address cell,FIND(" OR ", Email address cell))`

```
`=IF(ISERROR(FIND(" OR ",Email address cell))=TRUE, Email address cell,
 MID(Email address cell,FIND(" OR ",Email address cell)+3,LEN(Email address cell)-
 FIND(" OR ", Email address cell))`
```

Comment: In the second formula, it adds the OR also. How can I remove that too so I can get just the email address?

Comment: Updated to reflect. You need to add three to start the word after space and or.

Comment: I think the `+3` will give chance to get more characters from the extreme right. It is not removing the characters from the extreme left. So the `or` is still there.

Comment: Hehe...I put the + 3 behind the wrong Find. Try now.

Answer (score 2):

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(A1,SEARCH(" or ",A1)-1),A1)
```

or

```
=LEFT(A1,SEARCH(" or ", A1& " or ")-1)
```

You may need to replace my commas with semicolons

If you need to find the second email address, try:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," or ",REPT(" ",99)),99,99*2))
```

which can be extended if you have more than two.

Comment: This is an awesome answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If your cell where the email(s) is A1:

```
=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(" or ";A1));"";LEFT(A1;SEARCH(" or ";A1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

A formula may not be required. Replace `or` with `|` and then apply Text to Columns with `|` as the delimiter.